# Flash allow smoothing bluring at 100% zoom

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I applied 'allow smoothing' to the images in the library, but even in 100% zoom the images get blurred. Very weird. Is there somehow to avoid that behavior? I would expect that it smooth only if I redimention the images.

I tagged as flex also because I'm exporting a SWF with these images (and MCs) to use in a Flex project.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for the resize event and handle the smoothing there. Example: (works on my case (with Spark Image-class) but could use some work):

```
image.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, function():void{

if(image.width != image.measuredWidth){
      image.smoothBitmapContent = true;
 } else {
      image.smoothBitmapContent = false;
 }

}
```

Now the image is only smoothed when it isn't in it's native width.